# Symfony2. json output, serialize

Tags: symfony

a Symfony2 newbie question.

What do I miss in the following code (it returns a "Call to a member function getArrayResult() on a non-object)"

```
 /**
 * Lists all Post entities.
 *
 * @Route("/jsonout", name="Mario_Post_jsonout")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function jsonoutAction()
{
  $response = new Response();

  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
  $query = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('MarioBlogBundle:Post')
           ->createQueryBuilder('e')
           ->select('e')
           ->getQuery();

  $results = $query->execute();    
  $myArray = $results->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);  // neither ->getArrayResult(); 
  $response->setContent(json_encode($myArray));
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return $response;
}
```

Do I need to use a 'use Doctrine\ORM.....;' line? which one  exactly?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience the methods `getResult()` and `getArrayResult()` coming with the `$query` object not with `$result` object. So we don't want to use both `->execute()` and `getResult()` together. That's the mistake in your code. we can rewrite your code like,

```
public function jsonoutAction()
{
  $response = new Response();

  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
  $query = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('MarioBlogBundle:Post')
           ->createQueryBuilder('e')
           ->select('e')
           ->getQuery();

  $results = $query->getArrayResult();    //or   getResult(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

  $response->setContent(json_encode($results));
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return $response;
}
```

it will  get worked.

Comment: Yes, it works, Thks so much. Minor question: why do I need parameter 'e'? I do not find it in the docs.

Comment: I think it's the alias for the selected entity in query like, `SELECT id from employees e.....`

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1) You do not need to `execute` query, you can just say
    `$query->getResult()` which will return array of objects. If you
    want to have results as pure array you can use
    `$query->getArrayResult()` which will return array of found values.
    You also do not need to use `select('e')` if you want to select all
    columns.

2) If you want to get all records without any criteria and condition you can use `findAll();` which return array of all objects in your entity:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$results = $em->getRepository('MarioBlogBundle:Post')->findAll();
```

Now by installing and using this class [EntitySerializer](https://github.com/borisguery/bgylibrary/blob/master/library/Bgy/Doctrine/EntitySerializer.php) you can have array output or just JSON output (which you want). For your example it will be:

```
$entitySerializer = new Bgy\Doctrine\EntitySerializer($em);
$jsonOutput = $entitySerializer->toJson($results);
```